# Why do I get wrong output?

Tags: java, output, division

I am very new to Java and am trying to write a simple code. Here is the description: 
Write a program that prompts the user for a number X. Print the
numbers from 1 to X. However, in place of multiples of 4 print “qqqq”. In place of multiples of 7, print “seven”. If a number is divisible by both 4 and 7 print “qqqqseven”. It means if I input 4, my output should be 1, 2, 3, (qqqq), ...but I get 1(qqqq), 2(qqqq), 3(qqqq), 4(qqqq)..... Can anyone help me and let me know where I am doing wrong? Any help is appreciated. Than you.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{

    //Print Method
    System.out.println("Enter number upto which you want to print: ");
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x;
        x = input.nextInt();


    for(int i=1; i <= x; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(i);

    //if x is multiples of 4
    if (x % 4 == 0)
            System.out.println("qqqq");
    //if x is multiples of 7
    if (x % 7 == 0)
            System.out.println("seven");
    //if x is divisible by 4 and 7
    if (x % 4 == 0 && x % 7 == 0)
            System.out.println("qqqqseven");

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is to use the if condition from most specific to least specific. In you case the most specific condition is a divisor of 4 and 7, followed by divisor of 4, divisor fo 7 and finally the least specific one which means everything else. If you could arrage your if conditions in that order you'll get the result.

Note: It a good practice to close scanner or any resources that you open. :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter number upto which you want to print: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x;
        x = input.nextInt();

        for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
            if(i%4 == 0 && i%7 == 0) {
                System.out.println("qqqqseven");
            } else if(i%4 == 0) {
                System.out.println("qqqq");
            } else if(i%7 == 0){
                System.out.println("seven");
            } else {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
if (x % 4 == 0)
```

With

```
if (i % 4 == 0)
```

Do likewise for the other occurrences of %

To get the correct output for multiple of 28 you will need to modify you code to this:

```
if (i % 4 == 0 && i % 7 == 0) { // if i is a multiple of 28 (of both 4 & 7)
  System.out.println("qqqqseven");
}
else {
  if (i % 4 == 0) { // if i is multiples of 4
        System.out.println("qqqq");
  }
  else if (i % 7 == 0) { // if i is multiples of 7
        System.out.println("seven");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I made changes and now, my output is 1, 2, 3, 4, qqqq, 5, 6, 7, seven.... How can I replace qqqq and seven with 4 and 7? I am trying to learn so if you give me a hint I really appreciate it.